# Random Item From A Conditional List

Tags: excel, random, conditional-statements, formula

I use the following formula to output a random item from a list:

```
=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(Database!A1:A100)),1)
```

Is there a way to add certain conditions to this? For example, the database list students and test scores. I want to choose a random student provided his or her test scores are above 80%. The student's name is in column A and the test scores are in column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this "array formula", assuming scores are shown as %s

`=INDEX(Database!A1:A100,SMALL(IF(Database!B1:B100>=80%,ROW(Database!A1:A100)-MIN(ROW(Database!A1:A100))+1),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(Database!B1:B100,">=80%"))))`

Confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The `IF` function returns only the relative row numbers of the rows where % is >= 80% then `SMALL` chooses one of those row numbers at random - `INDEX` returns the name from that row as per your original formula

Comment: One follow up question, @barryhoudini - how do I amend the formula if I want the criteria to be referred to via another cell. So rather than hard-coding 80% into the formula, I would like to reference the condition that is stored in cell D1.